# Node.js & MySQL: HTTP server stops after first run

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using node-mysql. Below codes taken from http://blog.josedacruz.com/2013/07/19/learning-node-js-using-mysql/

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  port : 3306,
  database: 'aaa',
  user : 'root',
  password : 'z'
});

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHeader(200);
    res.write('Connect to mySql\n');
    // Connect to mySql (if there is an erro, report it and terminate de request)
    connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err != null) {
            res.end('Error connecting to mysql:' + err+'\n');
        }
    });

    connection.query("SELECT value FROM variable WHERE name = 'site_name'", function(err, rows){
        if(err != null) {
            res.end("Query error:" + err);
        } else {
            // Shows the result on console window
            console.log(rows[0]);
            res.end("Success!");
        }
        // Close connection
        connection.end();
    });
}).listen(80);
```

First thing first, I feel strange the `connection.end` not same level with `connection.connect`

I've tried change the `connection` to be same level and also put on different place, but still no luck

Below is the error in terminal when HTTP server stops after first run (note: `MyTube` is the result of query)

```
{ value: 'MyTube' }
 
Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:131:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:98:13)
    at Protocol.quit (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:61:36)
    at Connection.end (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:155:18)
    at Query._callback (/home/mydir/node/app.js:31:20)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:75:24)
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:153:6)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:98:13)
    at Connection.query (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:140:25)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/mydir/node/app.js:22:16)
    --------------------
    at Quit.Sequence (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
    at new Quit (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Quit.js:8:12)
    at Protocol.quit (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:61:45)
    at Connection.end (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:155:18)
    at Query._callback (/home/mydir/node/app.js:31:20)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:75:24)
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:153:6)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:98:13)
    at Connection.query (/home/mydir/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:140:25)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/mydir/node/app.js:22:16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to reuse a connection created by `mysql.createConnection` after that connection has been closed by `connection.end()`.

You need to move the call to `mysql.createConnection` to inside the callback to `http.createServer`, *or* (which I would recommend) use [connection pooling](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) instead.

Answer (score 1):

One way to quickly solve this is to remove your `connection.connect` and `connection.end` calls and rely on the implicit connection made by `connection.query`

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHeader(200);
    res.write('Connect to mySql\n');     
    connection.query("SELECT value FROM variable WHERE name = 'site_name'", function(err, rows){
        if(err != null) {
            res.end("Query error:" + err);
        } else {
            // Shows the result on console window
            console.log(rows[0]);
            res.end("Success!");
        }
    });
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: `node-mysql` queues operations so they don't have to be performed in the usual async way of waiting until a previous operation has finished. See [the introduction](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction).